# Multiclassing Silver Pyromancer: all fire spells cast at character level as caster level?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, multi-classing

The **Silver Pyromancer** class from Five Nations has this ability:

> Pyromancer: Whenever you cast a spell with the fire descriptor, use your character level as your caster level.

Let's say Bob is a level 16 multi-classed character with wizard 5/cleric 9/silver pyromancer 2.

His wizard caster level is 6 (5 + 1 from silver pyromancer), his cleric caster level is 9.

If he casts fireball (1d6/lvl max 10d6 damage, fire descriptor) as a wizard, he does 10d6 damage because of the Pyromancer class feature.

Flamestrike is a cleric spell with 1d6/lvl max 15d6 and the fire descriptor.
Does "Pyromancer" apply for the flamestrike spell too, for 15d6 damage?

If no, what rule applies here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Yes, pyromancer applies to all spells

It’s a little difficult to prove this, since the reason why is simply “because nothing says it doesn’t,” but that’s the answer: it says “when you cast a spell,” no if’s, and’s, or but’s. No matter where that spell comes from—arcane class, divine class, magic item, *whatever*, you get this benefit.

To at least help a little demonstrating that this is the case, consider a similar feature from the abjurant champion prestige class:

> **Martial Arcanist (Ex):** At 5th level, you master the art of combining your militant and mystical training. From this point on, your caster level in a chosen arcane spellcasting class is equal to your base attack bonus (unless it would otherwise be higher). For example, a 7th-level fighter/1st-level wizard/5th-level abjurant champion has a base attack bonus of +12 (and thus a caster level of 12th). You can apply this benefit to only one arcane class to which you have added spellcasting levels by your advancement as an abjurant champion.

<sup>(*Complete Mage*, pg. 50)</sup>

Note that it specifically says “a **chosen** arcane spellcasting class,” and “You can apply this benefit to **only one** arcane class,” and so on. This is what pyromancer would say if it were limited to spells of a specific class. It might even say something like this where it is an “arcane class to which you have added spellcasting levels by your advancement as [a silver pyromancer].” Since pyromancer **doesn’t** say that, it isn’t restricted that way.

Comment: RaI might have been "arcane only", or even "one arcane class only", if you look at the fluff, "arcane champion of the Church". However, as you note, the feature presents no such qualifiers - FLAME ON!

Comment: @From The fact that the class requires turn undead suggests a certain amount of multiclassing was anticipated, though. After all, “**Becoming a Silver Pyromancer** Most silver pyromancers are wizards with a single level of cleric,” _Five Nations_ pg. 150.

Comment: That's a Sacred Exorcist dip if I ever saw one! Keep your Arcane caster level where it should be. ;)

Comment: @From Delaying your 1st level of silver pyromancer until 11th is rough in a setting where 13th is about the limit of plausible mortal power, though.

Comment: 11th? Oh, Dismissal? Arcane Disciple (Balance) nets you that at 7, so you can clock in for Silver Pyromancer at 9th. Still, yes, that's 2 levels later than with a Cleric dip. Also, why does SE remove me @-ing your name?

Comment: @From Because it’s my answer, so I get pinged anyway, so it’s pointless to include it (and you might want to @ someone else and ping us both).